# Return the entire query if the filter is empty in phonograph2

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

I am trying to make a date filter within the query in phonograph so that if the date filter is empty it returns the entire query

[image]

Preview Rendered Query

[image]

However, I am not very familiar with the language, I am not able to do it correctly and it is generating this error

[image]

Could someone who is more familiar with the language explain me where I am going wrong and teach me how to make the entire query return if the filter is empty or null

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following code block to apply a range filter. Specifically if you only need the one range filter, and not multiple filters, this should be the simplest solution

```
{
  "tableRids": [
    "{{f_getTableId}}"
  ],
  "filter": {
    "type": "range",
    "range": {
      "field": "your_field_name",
      "gte": "your_value"
      "lte": "your_other_value"
    }
  }
}
```

In your rendered request as well, the input variable `{{inicio_input.value}}` is currently rendering to an empty string. This would not return a valid response when trying the query, so when testing it I recommend putting in some test values like `1` and `10` or other range that you expect would return a non zero result.

Final note - the `matchAll` block is only used if you want to return all rows with this table an aggregate them. In your case, it looks like you just want to apply a filter, in which case the above code should work.

Query examples can be found on the docs here - https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/references-writeback/#query-examples